# How to keep a QSlider activated to allow movements with arrows at any time

Tags: c++, qt, arrow-keys, qslider

I would like to be able to move a `QSlider` with arrows of the keyboard at any time.

I want to be able to click anywhere on the QWindow and keep `QSlider` activated to move the cursor with the arrows.

My problem is that move the cursor with arrows is only allowed if we click on the `QSlider` before.

I hope my question is clear enough.

Does anyone know how to move the `QSlider` with arrows of the keyboard without clicking on the `QSlider` before please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1. In Qt terms, you'd like to give slider the focus. Widgets have the `setFocus` method, so you need to call `slider->setFocus(Qt::OtherFocusReason)`.

   Since you want the slider to get focus whenever the underlying window has focus, you need to put the `setFocus` call in your implementation of `focusInEvent` for the parent widget.
2. You can forward the key events from the underlying widget to the slider. In the parent widget, reimplement `keyPressEvent` and `keyReleaseEvent`. When the desired keys are detected, forward them to the slider:

   ```
   // same for keyReleaseEvent!
   void MyWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * ev) {
     if (ev->key() == Qt::Key_Up || ev->key() == Qt::Key_Down) {
       slider->event(ev);
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Ok thank you I made it. I add the code `slider->setFocus();` before the `if` in the code you sent me and I also do the same for keyReleaseEvent as you said.